# What does the /2 /3 mean in prolog?

Tags: prolog

What do those `/2 /3` that I see in example code do?

Like this one:

```
4 ?- trace([equals,contains]).

% equals/2: [call, redo, exit, fail]

% contains/2: [call, redo, exit, fail]
```

Comment: This (in this context) is called a predicate indicator.

Answer (score 4):

[Learn Prolog Now!](http://www.learnprolognow.org/) is a nice tutorial.

In Prolog, lines starting with a '%' are comments.

`equals/2` describes a functor named `equals` with the arity of two, which means that it expects two arguments.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reference book link and even more for the helpful answer.